# What is the proper way to shell script a start / stop process that is triggered by another process?

Tags: bash, shell, script

Program 1 runs irregularly, and crashes program 2, which then crashes program 1.

I'm not able to find the proper way to make program 2 stop when program 1 is initiated, and then restart program 2 when program one quits.  I'm tired of having to manually do this, and I have been searching for a solution for the past few hours.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a combination of trap and exit in a wrapper script should help ....

like on encountering the process prog2 in ps -ef | grep prog2 , you can use exit in wrapper to send signal to trap - using trap you can specify what action to do like normal exit or force kill ie kill -9 PID_progX !!

wrapper is something like a controling script that will start , stop and monitor the process so that you dont have to start or stop them your self.